# Parsing complex Xml Python 3.4

Tags: python, xml

I have the following xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Suite>
<TestCase>
  <TestCaseID>001</TestCaseID>
  <TestCaseDescription>Hello</TestCaseDescription>
  <TestSetup>
    <Action>
      <ActionCommand>gfdg</ActionCommand>
      <TimeOut>dfgd</TimeOut>
      <BamSymbol>gff</BamSymbol>
      <Side>vfbgc</Side>
      <PrimeBroker>fgfd</PrimeBroker>
      <Size>fbcgc</Size>
      <PMCode>fdgd</PMCode>
      <Strategy>fdgf</Strategy>
      <SubStrategy>fgf</SubStrategy>
      <ActionLogEndPoint>fdgf</ActionLogEndPoint>
      <IsActionResultLogged>fdgf</IsActionResultLogged>
      <ValidationStep>
        <IsValidated>fgdf</IsValidated>
        <ValidationFormat>dfgf</ValidationFormat>
        <ResponseEndpoint>gdf</ResponseEndpoint>
        <ResponseParameterName>fdgfdg</ResponseParameterName>
        <ResponseParameterValue>gff</ResponseParameterValue>
        <ExpectedValue>fdgf</ExpectedValue>
        <IsValidationResultLogged>gdfgf</IsValidationResultLogged>
        <ValidationLogEndpoint>fdgf</ValidationLogEndpoint>
      </ValidationStep>
    </Action>
    <Action>
      <ActionCommand>New Order</ActionCommand>
      <TimeOut>fdgf</TimeOut>
      <BamSymbol>fdg</BamSymbol>
      <Side>C(COVER)</Side>
      <PrimeBroker>CSPB</PrimeBroker>
      <Size>fdgd</Size>
      <PMCode>GREE</PMCode>
      <Strategy>Generalist</Strategy>
      <SubStrategy>USLC</SubStrategy>
      <ActionLogEndPoint>gfbhgf</ActionLogEndPoint>
      <IsActionResultLogged>fdgf</IsActionResultLogged>
      <ValidationStep>
        <IsValidated>fdgd</IsValidated>
        <ValidationFormat>dfgfd</ValidationFormat>
        <ResponseEndpoint>dfgf</ResponseEndpoint>
        <ResponseParameterName>fdgfd</ResponseParameterName>
        <ResponseParameterValue>dfgf</ResponseParameterValue>
        <ExpectedValue>fdg</ExpectedValue>
        <IsValidationResultLogged>fdgdf</IsValidationResultLogged>
        <ValidationLogEndpoint>fdgfd</ValidationLogEndpoint>
      </ValidationStep>
    </Action>
    </TestCase>
</Suite>
```

Based on the ActionCommand i am getting either one block , the issue is could not get the sub parent tag (ValidationStep) and all its child tags . Can anyone help?

My code:

```
for testSetup4 in root.findall(".TestCase/TestSetup/Action"):
     if testSetup4.find('ActionCommand').text == "gfdg":
         for c1 in testSetup4:
            t2.append(c1.tag)
            v2.append(c1.text)

         for k,v in zip(t2, v2):
            test_case[k] = v
```

I am not able to get ValidationStep (sub parent) and its corresponding tags.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add another loop to iterate through the `<ValidationStep>` node and its children. Also, you do not need the two other lists as you can update a dictionary during the parsing loop:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

dom = et.parse('Input.xml')
root = dom.getroot()

test_case = {}
for testSetup4 in root.findall(".TestCase/TestSetup/Action"):
     if testSetup4.find('ActionCommand').text == "gfdg":
        for c1 in testSetup4:
            test_case[c1.tag]= c1.text
        for vd in testSetup4.findall("./ValidationStep/*"):
            test_case[vd.tag]= vd.text
```

Alternatively, use the double slash operator to search for all children including grandchildren of `<Action>` element:

```
for testSetup4 in root.findall(".TestCase/TestSetup/Action"):
     if testSetup4.find('ActionCommand').text == "gfdg":
         for c1 in testSetup4.findall(".//*"):
            test_case[c1.tag]= c1.text
```